# Social network analysis - Find the smallest set of people knowing everyone

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, social-networking

I have a social network represented as a set of people `S` and individual weights for each of person (weight is the cost of person).
I also have defined relationships between these people (whether people know each other or not).
I must find such a subset `D`, such that every person in this subset either belongs to the set `S` or knows someone from the set `S`.

There will be a lot of such subsets.
I want the subset whose sum of weights of people is the smallest.

I have no idea how to solve this problem.
I thought to create a undirected graph where:

- Each vertex represents person.
- Each vertex has a weight assigned to it.
- Edges between vertices indicate whether the people know each other or not.

Is it a good idea?
Which graph algorithms can be useful to me?

EDIT:
TO: Arnol Singh Jaggi

No, I mean something else. Only directly relationships are permitted. That's mean in your example answer is Adam(15) since he covers the entire set S - he is itself in a subset D and directly knows John and Viktor.

Let's see this example:

{John(7), Adam(15), Viktor(6), Bob(2)} and connections are John - Adam - Viktor - Bob. Solutions are Adam,Bob(17) OR John,Victor(13) OR Adam,Victor(21) OR John,Bob(9). The best is the last one - John,Bob(9).

I imagine this as a minimum spanning tree on directed graphs problem. I found Chu-Liu/Edmond's algorithm, I know that this algorithm works for edge-weighted graphs and I have vertices-weighted, so I just set the edge weights to what are the weights of the vertices at the end of the edge. But this is not optimal solution. I don't need direct connections between people in the set D.

So after I have result from that algorithm, I can apply on it some greedy algorithm, which will go recursively over each element and check how removing it from the subset D will affect the structure - when the sum of the weights will be minimal and will ensure that no element falls out of set D (check below).

Refer to an example, my MST result will be John,Adam,Victor,Bob(27). Best solution is John,Bob(9). Interesting bad solution is Viktor,Bob(8) - the sum is minimal, unfortunately John will fall out of the D subset.

Assuming that it is possible to reach each vertex from any other vertex, I think searching all the connected components will be wrong.

After explaining how it works exactly, do you suggest any different solution?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/129113/755, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/80001/8560, https://stackoverflow.com/q/63322695/781723, https://or.stackexchange.com/q/4650/2415.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `I must find such a subset D, such that every person in this subset either belongs to the set S or knows someone from the set S` means that every person in D either belongs to S or knows someone from S directly or **indirectly**.
Meaning that if the set S is `{John(10), Adam(15), Viktor(6)}` and connections are `John - Adam - Viktor`, then the answer set `D` will be `Viktor(6)` since Viktor directly knows Adam and indirectly knows John.

With tha above assumption, your graph modelling is correct.
Find all the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) in the undirected graph.
Lets say there are n connected components.
Now find the vertex with the lowest weight in each of those components.
You'll get n vertices , one from each component.

The answer subset D is this set of these n vertices.

This is the most efficient algorithm possible for this problem since time complexity is linearly proportional to the number of vertices + edges.

[Here](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/interview-notes/blob/master/notes/algo-ds-practice/problems/graph/standard/connected_components/undirected/connected_components_undirected_dfs.py) is a simple implementation of connected components using DFS.

EDIT:

I guess what you are looking for is the [minimum vertex cover](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vertex-cover-problem-set-2-dynamic-programming-solution-tree/) problem for undirected graphs.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: My answer to your comment is too long to post it here, please check my edited answer above.

Comment: you're right, the answer is mminimum vvertex cover.